# Mongodb Management Service Error, Failure dialing host

Tags: azure, mongodb-mms

I've downloaded MMS by using this command

```
curl -OL https://mms.mongodb.com/download/agent/monitoring/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent_latest_amd64.deb
```

Installed it by using sudo

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent_latest_amd64.deb
```

And edited /monitoring-agent.config file which located in

```
/etc/mongodb-mms
```

It was working Just fine Until I've started my mongod rplSet by adding --Fork flag, and by using this command

```
sudo mongod --fork --port 27017 --dbpath /mydbpath --logpath /mylogpath/mongodb.log --replSet Rplname
```

After starting the services using the above command, my MMS started showing that the host is Unreachable, and that following msg, in all of the members.

```
Task failure `hostIpAddr`. Err: `Failure determining IPv4 address for `myDnsAdd.cloudapp.net`. Err: `myDnsAdd.cloudapp.net: no such host` at monitoring-agent/components/task.go:221 at monitoring-agent/components/worker.go:153 at monitoring-agent/components/worker.go:224 at monitoring-agent/components/worker.go:236 at pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445`
```

I've edited the hosts file, and added the hosts ips and hostnames.
Opened the 443 port, and tried to start mmms with --system flag like this

```
sudo start mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent --system
```

But still, Host is Unreachable. I got access list on the mongoport (:27017) is it beacuse of this? if so what IP should I add to that access list?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OS is Ubuntu 14.04, then this link should be interesting for you:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS-2202

Basically it says that it is a bug in glibc and the solution for this guy was to update Ubuntu to version **14.10**.